# Confusing syntax errors

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am making a tool to test DNS connection speeds in Visual Basic mostly as a learning experience. I originally was using this field declaration:

```
' Initialize the list of DNS providers and domains
Private dnsProviders As New List(Of String) From {
    "8.8.8.8",  ' Google
    "1.1.1.1",  ' Cloudflare
    "208.67.222.222"  ' OpenDNS
}
```

which I got errors with so I changed to

```
Private dnsProviders As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)({
    "8.8.8.8",  ' Google
    "1.1.1.1",  ' Cloudflare
    "208.67.222.222"  ' OpenDNS
})
```

but now I am trying to fix the second part of my code and am stilling getting syntax errors `'}' expected` and `')' expected`

```
Private domainsToTest As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)({
    "google.com",
    "facebook.com",
    "twitter.com",
    "microsoft.com",
    "apple.com"
})
```

What exactly am I missing?

Comment: Looks correct. Maybe you have a syntax mishap one line before that (or you removed a trailing comma in the code posted here) -- To use from, you have to declare the Type first, as in `Private dnsProviders as List(Of String) = New List(Of String) from { ... }`

Comment: I mean, if the last entry has a comma, e.g., `"apple.com",`  that's not accepted (maybe you code in C (something))

Comment: What version of VB are you using?

Comment: To pick up @jmcihinney's line: Try to add a `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` to your first `<PropertyGroup>` within your (SDK-style) project file(s) (`*.vbproj`).